# feature file ignore the Steps Definition and ignored Test

Tags: java, cucumber

feature file ignore the Steps Definition and ignored Test

Issue :

The steps are defined and I can navigate to them through feature file but when i run it, it ignore the steps and suggest "You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:"[image: Error Message]

Can someone please have a look and kindly provide your feedback as i am not able to workout the problem?

[[image: Steps[][2][2]]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try changing the glue to the folder path rather to the file path. Remove the file name at the end of the glue. `src/main/java/steps`

Comment: Hi. It did not make any difference.

Comment: Sorry, change the folder name to `stepDefinition`

Comment: Hi. I think the naming conventions are not an issue here. but i try stepDefinition and it is not working.

Comment: U should ideally move the java code in main folder into the test folder. Change the glue option in runner to "Steps".

Comment: Hi tried all the recommended changes but the issue remain same. :(

Comment: Did you make any changes on your cucumber dependencies like info.cukes to io.cucumber? @SushantTavrawala

Comment: @SelçukAyhan no. the problem is if i create a new feature file than it does not glue the steps. It is working fine with the existing files. which is really strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer of this issue.

In the Runner Class, With GLUE instead of giving full path, if you give just Package name than it pick up the steps.

[image]

Comment: The another issue was, the error was caused by a plugin called Substep IntelliJ Plugin. You need to search for it in the IntelliJ Plugin Section and disable or deinstall it.